# Getting started with the Friendly ORM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schemaless

I'm following this tutorial: http://friendlyorm.com/

I'm using InstantRails to run MySQL locally. To run Ruby and Rails, I'm using normal Windows installations.

When I run `Friendly.create_tables!` I only get an empty Array returned: `=> []` and no tables are created in my 'friendly_development' database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of Friendly here.

You'll have to require all of your models before calling Friendly.create_tables! Otherwise, there's no way for Friendly to know which models exist. In a future revision, I'll automatically preload all your models.

Comment: how do I do that?
Require 'CamelCasedModelName'?

Comment: require 'the_name_of_the_file_that_contains_my_model'

Answer (score 1):

I have a rake task, with help from a guy called Sutto, that will load in all your models and then call Friendly.create_tables! and print out all the tables involved.

```
namespace :friends do
  desc "load in all the models and create the tables"
  task :create => :environment do
    puts "-----------------------------------------------"
    Dir[Rails.root.join("app", "models", "*.rb")].each { |f|File.basename(f, ".rb").classify.constantize }
    tables = Friendly.create_tables!
    tables.each do |table|
      puts "Table '#{table}'"
    end
    puts "-----------------------------------------------"
  end
end

rake friends:create
```

Answer (score 0):

not much to go on here.  My guess is that it can't find your model file that you are creating in the path?

Comment: my model is called BlogPost which is in app/models/blog_post.rb.
Have you used Friendly?